# On radio check do this else do that in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a radio button like this in a rails app.

```
  <div class="radio_button_with_text">
          <%=radio_button  "lsb" ,"name",l.name ,checked: false,:onclick=>"save_label('#{l.photo.url}',#{l.id}); "%>
        <p class="radioText"><%= l.name %>
        </p>
 </div>
```

then I have this in other file

```
 <div id = "file">
   <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "check_radio_click()"> 
   <img id="image11" class="img-responsive loadbtn"style="display:inline;position:relative;width:125px;left: 108px;" src="../assets/buttons/Nextbtn.png" >
   </a>
 </div>
```

So there's a radio button and a next button.

What I am trying to do is, give an alert If no radio button is checked on the click of next button. And If clicked on click of Next button redirect to another page using `window.location`.

I am not able to get that working.

Please suggest.

UPDATE 1: This is how I am trying to do it.

```
<script >
   function check_radio_click(){
     $('#image11').click(function() {
       if($('.radio_button_with_text').is(':checked')) {
          alert("it's checked");
           }
       else{
          alert("Please select at least one LABEL");
           }
      });
   }
 </script>
```

UPDATE 2:

So, I gave a class to my `radio button` in the `rails tag` like below and

```
  <%=radio_button  class: "radio_input_class" "lsb" ,"name",l.name ,checked: 
   false,:onclick=>"save_label('#{l.photo.url}',#{l.id}); "%>
```

changed my script like this

```
$('#image11').click(function() {
  if($('.radio_input_class').is(':checked')) {
    alert("it's checked");
       }
       else{
    alert("Please select at least one LABEL");
       }
     });
```

This is not working either.

Comment: You can check this on `click` event of button if radio button is checked or not. You can use `is(":checked")`

Comment: Could this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-required

Comment: somehow this is not doing the trick for me 

`$('#image11').click(function() {
   if($('.radio_button_with_text').is(':checked')) {
    alert("it's checked");
       }
});

    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/753pn038/2/)

#### Code

```js
function validate() {
    console.log($("input[name=rbTest]").is(":checked"))
    return $("input[type=radio]").is(":checked")
}

function submit(){
 if(validate()){
     console.log("Redirecting...")
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="test"  name="rbTest">Test
<input type="radio" value="test1" name="rbTest">Test 1
<input type="radio" value="test2" name="rbTest">Test 2
<button onclick="submit()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: I know this logic, but I am not able to get it working with the rails and with my code

Comment: Apologies! I'm have 0 knowledge about rails, but is `check_radio_click()` a function on JS or rails?

Comment: Then it should ideally. Try `console.log($('.radio_button_with_text'))` if you are getting elements or not

Comment: @Suraj just a pointer, class `radio_button_with_text` is assigned to div and not radio buttons :-p

Comment: yeah, I saw that and tried by giving class to the radio button tag in rails, even that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
if($('input:radio:checked').length > 0) {
    alert('checked');
}else {
    alert('unchecked');
}
```